# Neural networks backpropagation

Tags: neural-networks

I was reading chapter 2 of Michael Nielsen's book on deep learning:
[image]

Shouldn't the circle word read "forward" instead of "backward" because we are using the weighted inptut to layer l?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as the previous sentence, with "backward" italicized states, a measure of the error is moving from layer $l + 1$ *back* to layer $l$. This is reducing the layer index, i.e., going backwards among the numbered activation layers.

This section of text is, as the title states, discussing [Backpropagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation) which is an important aspect giving a lot of the power of artificial neural networks and deep learning.